# Can we choose polarization vectors freely in any given gauge theory?

Tags: gauge-theory, polarization

When quantizing a gauge theory, we obtain spin-1 particles propagating in space-time. When we want to count the degrees of freedom of the theory or, equivalently, when we are trying to decompose the field operator in a LI basis, we use polarization vectors. My question is, in any given gauge choice, for any given gauge theory, can we choose polarization vectors however we like, as long as they form a basis?

For example, can I choose these?

\begin{equation}
\epsilon_0=(1,0,0,0)\\ \epsilon_1=(0,1,0,0) \\ \epsilon_2=(0,0,1,0) \\ \epsilon_3=(0,0,0,1)
\end{equation}

Or any linear combination of those? like choosing $\epsilon_{\pm}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\epsilon_0 \pm\epsilon_3\big)$ which are called the forward and backward polarization vectors. I know probably some choices are smarter than others, but my question is whether we are free to choose whichever basis we want.

Comment: See a similar question regarding [polarization and QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190394/how-is-polarization-vector-in-qft-related-to-polarization-in-classical-electrody)